# Will Apple reject my app with Cora Data warning regarding too many attributes?

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm using Core Data (with sqlite) in an iOS app and an entity has up to 200 attributes. I realize this is a lot, but this is the suitable number of attributes on my app.

Xcode is now giving me a warning: "Misconfigured Entity: Entity has more than 100 properties; consider a more shallow entity hierarchy or denormalized properties."

What I want to know are two things as follows;

1. Will Apple reject my app due to the warning? (If you have experiences to release your app with the warning, please let me know it.)
2. Is there a way to suppress the warning? (Like @SuppressWaring annotation on Java)

Any help will be gratefully appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: No your app will not get rejected because of these warnings.

Comment: @Rog Thanks, I am relieved to hear that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't imagine your app will get rejected for that specifically, but if you have 200 attributes, I suspect you are doing other things wrong that you may get rejected for.

You should review your data model and consider breaking apart that entity into several smaller entities.

Comment: Thanks, I was very relieved. Yes, You are right. 200 attributes are too many. I will review it.